# read random lines from a record MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

i will keep it simple to understand :

1) i have a database with 2 columns - word and text

2) Each word has approx. 600,000 lines of text associated with it.

3) Iam a .net person shifting to php and mysql - so a little knowledge.

MY requirement :

1) I will pass the word through a form

2) The form will connect to the database and should display 2000 random lines from those 600,000 which should be non-repetitive

My current progress :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","text_minx","pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Data
WHERE word='health'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['lines'];
  echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

This shows all the lines. What i want is to read this $row['lines'] in a possible array and randomly select 2000 lines from it - and they should be non-repetitive.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Data WHERE word='health' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2000");
```

It's more efficient to select the 2000 random lines by MySQL instead of by PHP, as above.

Also note that `SELECT DISTINCT` will select only unique rows, which you should probably remove anyway. If you specify the column names instead of using `*` then you can choose which columns you want to be unique - although this also depends somewhat on how your table is built.

Comment: hello, i do not want 2000 records. I want 2000 lines from a single record :). So i get all data and want 2000 lines from them using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the way you want

SELECT * FROM Data
WHERE word='health' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2000

this will give you 2000 records sorted by any random order

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your row result into array (as it's currently a string), and then you can select 2000 lines randomly.

Assuming that the text has like breaks as line separators, it would look like that:

```
echo $row['lines']; //starts from this line of your code
$data = explode("\n", $row['lines']);
shuffle($data);
$random_lines = array_slice($data, 0, 2000);
```

This does not take care of non-repetition, though. If I understand your need correctly, you can use `array_unique()` function before passing it to shuffle().